# How to solve $\left\lfloor y_1 2^z\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor y_2 2^z\right\rfloor =x$ for $z$ in terms of $y_1,y_2$ and $x$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Question: Solve $\left\lfloor y_1 2^z\right\rfloor -\left\lfloor y_2 2^z\right\rfloor =x$ for $z$ in terms of $y_1,y_2$ and $x$.

Without the floors it's pretty simple algebra but I don't know what operations I can perform on the floors.

Comment: Are those values integers? Are you thinking of a specific case?

Comment: z and x are integers, y1 and y2 are decimals. Essentially I'm trying to find the maximum zoom level for a map given a bounding box and max image size https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames#Mathematics

Comment: Not sure that it can be solved exactly completely, but from the context I think you're programming? If so, you can solve for $2^z$ first by considering the values when $\lfloor y_1k\rfloor$ and $\lfloor y_2k\rfloor$ change, then take logarithm.